# Open subpage through navigation in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created 3 new views in asp.net MVC 3 Home directory. When i try to acces any of them through navigation I get 404 error. I try to access them with this code:

```
<ul id="menu">
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hobbies", "Hobbies", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Accessin predefined pages Home and About works well. Where is the catch?

P.S. I'm using default mvc3 Layout for master page

Comment: What do you mean on " acces any of them through navigation"? So typing the URL in a browser?  How an example URL look like? What are the names of the views? Where have you put them the project? Do they have a controller?

Comment: What I meant was: I press one of the navigation buttons on master page, i.e. Hobbies. The view Hobbies should then open in the body of master page. But when I click the button I get 404 error. I created views in Project/Home in VS2010. They don't have a controller. Example URL is: http://localhost:50060/Home/Hobbies

Comment: You have Action Hobbies, right? can you show us your controller?

Comment: I only have two controllers in my Project; AccountController.cs and HomeController.cs, which are the defaults

Comment: I just read some guide and found out a few things. Shouldn't have started building a project before obtaining some basic knowledge :)

Comment: Please add your code from HomeController